# wlan0 device not found

Tags: wireless

I am not able to connect to my wifi as my wifi adapter is not getting detected. I have tried a lot of solutions online, but nothing seems to be working.

ifconfig wlan0

wlan0: error fetching interface information: Device not found

When I do ifconfig, it showed a docker0 interface which previously wasnt there. So I uninstalled docker, but the wlan0 still isnt getting detected. Is there any solution for this?

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/tWtgHhQv2H/

Comment: Please start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: I have added the txt file of the script to the above link in the question.

Comment: Please note: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] and check the duplicate.

Comment: I am getting the following error after executing sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source. It says that :
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.4.0-119-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.4.0-119-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom/build/make.log for more information.
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-119-generic

Comment: What does this tell us? `gcc --version` Possibly helpful: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gcc-4.8/+bug/1750937

Comment: Yeah I fixed that issue by installing gcc4.9 and making it default. Now I'm getting the error                        modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Exec format error